# Xcode 7.2 error inspectors showing empty

Tags: xcode, xcode7.2

Xcode 7.2 error, xcode shows all inspectors are empty even after selecting any element.
What kind of error is this and how to solve this? 
(Problem arose instantly after I installed a CocoaPod)

[image: attributes inspector not showing]
[image: size inspector not showing]
[image: connections inspector not showing]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my storyboard. I managed to repair my inspectors by selecting other XIB and selecting any element there in order to see one of it's inspectors on the right. Than I switched back to my storyboard and my inspectors stopped being empty.

Answer (score 0):

I tried restarting my Mac but still the problem existed (this had solved issue for friend before).
I don't know why this problem came, but on updating pods of my project solved this issue.

In terminal, changed directory to my project and hit.

```
pod update
```